# Baking trouble using a cage

Tags: modeling

I have created a high poly model of a castle wall and I would like to save on rendering time by baking the detail to a low poly counterpart.

I followed this Tutorial : https://bit.ly/2Iy3WF7

However when I come to bake I get an error message saying the following : Invalid cage object, the cage mesh must have the same number of faces as the active object.

I'm assuming the active object is the low poly mesh. But in the image example you can clearly see that they do have the same number of faces. is this a bug or have I done something wrong.

[image: As you can see the faces of both the low poly and cage are the same]

Comment: be careful - info in status bar is for all scene objects.

Comment: I don't believe that it is because it changes when I click on different meshes.

Answer (score 2):

When selecting the active object use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Click instead of <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Click.

Answer (score 1):

The error message isn't quite specific enough.  It's not merely the same number of faces that matters-- the cage needs to have identical topology (including vertex order) to the low poly.  Blender needs to create a correspondence between points on the cage and points on the low poly, and to do that, it relies on shared topology.

Like in your video: create your cage by duplicating your low poly.  (Neither should have any modifiers, probably.)  And then, when editing your cage, do not perform any topology changing operations: no dissolve or delete anything, no knife, no triangulate operations, no rotate edge, etc.  Only use simple move, rotate, scale, shrink/fatten operations.